# Can't install opencv or import cv2 in google datalab

Tags: python, opencv, google-cloud-datalab

I'm running a jupyter notebook in google datalab running python 3. I'd like to use cv2 but am unable to import the module.

I was able to install opencv using:

```
!pip install opencv-python
```

I got the following confirmation:

> Collecting opencv-python
>     Using cached opencv_python-3.4.0.12-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
>
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from opencv-python)
>
> Installing collected packages: opencv-python
>
> Successfully installed opencv-python-3.4.0.12

When I try to "import cv2" I get the following error:

> importError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import cv2
>
> ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

When I list the modules using

```
help("modules")
```

neither opencv or cv2 are shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the above answers haven't solved your problem, try:

`!pip3 install opencv-python`

In Datalab 'pip' is 'pip2', so for python 3 installs you have to use pip3.

Answer (score 1):

It's *opencv-python*, not *python-opencv*.

Use this command to install cv2.

```
!apt-get -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python
```

Shows cv2 version from my colab notebook

[image: Shows cv2 version from my colab notebook]

BTW, if you still have some problem, try to Restart Runtime.

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped it in my question, I did run `!pip install opencv-python` originally. I tried your command in the notebook but got the error **E: Unable to locate package libsm6
E: Unable to locate package libxext6** I also tried using just `!apt-get install opencv-python` but got the error **E: Unable to locate package opencv-python** Also tried resetting with no success. I'm not familiar with colab, I'm using jupyter notebook, could that be an issue?

Comment: So far I count 4 options for doing ML through google? that's too many options for a noob like me. is there a comparative guide to help one decide which to use?

Comment: Votes are anonymous here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198962/anonymous-downvotes-ruining-stack-overflow-for-new-users-driving-them-away-from

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It worked when I ran

```
!apt-get update
```

before the install command.
You might have to run `apt-get install` with the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag though.

Comment: Are you running python 2 or 3? My original issue came running python 3 but when i switched to 2 it seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: When you are using python 3 you need to run pip3 instead.